ntpq query request timed out
I have deployed ntpsec pod in kubernetes using the helm chart. And I need to collect the peer metrics of the ntpsec for which I am using ntpq -p -n <LB_VIP>. My motto is to run the ntpq command out side the pod by running it against the load balance vip of the ntpsec pod. But it
timed out, nothing received ***Request timed out
but when I use ntplib python library to get some data of ntpsec running against the same LB ipaddress it gives me the details.
can anybody help me understand how can I acheieve the peer metrics of ntpsec by running ntpq against the LB ipaddress of the pod?
I want to use this
ntpq -p -n <LB_ip of the pod>
to get the below result
result
 remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.002
 1.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.002
 2.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.002
 3.ubuntu.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.002
 ntp.ubuntu.com  .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.002


check your firewall. looks like you have no connections to the pool.
